# Xubuntu Desktop shuts down and goes to login screen

Tags: xubuntu

I will be humming along just fine and then all of a sudden the desktop shuts down and goes to the login screen. I can then put my password back in and it will open back up the desktop. It does not show any error notifications that are visible. I installed Lubuntu along alongside Xbuntu to see if that would correct the problem but Lubuntu does the same thing. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be happening?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should look on the Xorg logs:

```
cd /var/log && tail Xorg.0.log
```

To a more complet look on the log do this:

```
gedit Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu, I am able to pull up the logs but dont know what to look for. Should I post them?

Comment: Yes, if you want to. But post it on pastebin.com to make easier to check.

Comment: Ok I pasted the cd /var/log && tail Xorg.0.log at this url:  http://pastebin.com/9ks4Ksje     I tried to pull the second log up and its blank.

Comment: Seems like the last lines don't tell much, so look on the whole log and try to find some error with "gedit Xorg.0.log" or "cat Xorg.0.log".

Comment: I pulled up  "gedit Xorg.0.log" and "cat Xorg.0.log  and both of those come up blank in the gedit.

Comment: I shoud also advance to you that your problem is probably with driver version. Do you use open source or proprietary drivers?

You should try looking at here:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29_BETA.2FEXPERIMENTAL